# how to create change set for Data Category

Tags: sandbox

How to create change set for Data Category in the salesforce .AM trying to create change set for data category but am not able to find the add component list of data category in that list .

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can use change sets and salesforce recommends a manual migration:

> Using Metadata API to deploy category changes from one organization to
>   another permanently removes categories and record categorizations that
>   are not specified in your XML file. Salesforce.com recommends that you
>   manually create data categories and record associations in an
>   organization from Setup by clicking Customize | Data Categories rather
>   than deploying changes from a sandbox to a production organization.
>   For more information, see [Usage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_datacategorygroup.htm#dcg_usage).